# Can't install gdal

Tags: python, pycharm, gdal

Is there too many frameworks in my mac? How should I make it right?

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - gdal -> numpy 1.8* -> python 2.6* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

[image]